# PassportJs is retrieving data with any clientID and clientSecret

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, ionic3, passport.js

Google Plus Token Strategy:

```
passport.use('googleToken', new GooglePlusTokenStrategy({
  clientID: 'adf',
  clientSecret: 'asdf'
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  console.log(accessToken);
  console.log(profile);
  return done(false, profile)
}));
```

> I'm passing the `access_token` as query string from the android client side.

The `accessToken` and the `profile` has been successfully retrieved with any cliendId and clientSecret! So what is the  purpose of using those keys?

And by the way,  the cliendID is only required for the Android google plus authentication, but the clientSecret is required for the server side (Nodejs) as well! but this clientSecret is not generated by the [google console](https://console.developers.google.com/) for android credentials

Comment: My understanding is that valid client Id and secret are needed in order to get an access token. Once an access token is available, it gets used _without_ client Id and secret.

Answer (score 0):

The client id and secrete are used for authentication (to make sure you're who you said you're) while the tokens are for authorization (to see what resources you have the right to access).

acessToken are used to call any services that you included in the scope when making the request (Gmail, google map, or youtube API). accessTokens are short-lived, so once they expired you can use the refreshToken to request the accessToken again.

However, it's possible that you don't have to use them at all if you're just authenticating the user through oAuth.

Make sure to keep them safe and don't leak them anywhere.

[image]

[image]